# Find json object without tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Say we have the following

```html
<title> Hello world! </title>
<span class="something">Here is some text</span>
{foo:{bar:1},alpha:2,beta:{donkey:horse}}
```

and I want to extract the dictionary/json object in python.
Since it is not in a tag, I struggle using `soup.find_all` in an easy way for this - is the best way to use regex for it, or any better idea? Note the dict could be anywhere on the webpage i.e not always as the last part on the webpage

Comment: Is there a real `class`? Can you search by the class name, in your example: `class="something"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. Assuming 'beta' is every json object

```
h = ''''<title> Hello world! </title>
<span class="something">Here is some text</span>
{foo:{bar:1},alpha:2,beta:{donkey:horse}}'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(h, "html.parser")
soup.find_all(string=re.compile('beta'))
```

Here's the output (a list). The page break is most likely from how read it as a string.

```
['\n{foo:{bar:1},alpha:2,beta:{donkey:horse}}']
```

Comment: That works - is it possible to grap only a subset of the json i.e `soup.find(string=re.compile("beta")`, returning `{"donkey":"horse"}` ?

Comment: you'd probably have to grab the dictionary and just parse it like any other dictionary. If json.loads() or something similar doesn't work, you could split('beta: ') and keep splitting until you get desired answer. Or someone with more regex experience can provide regex syntax to pull it out.

Comment: I think my question was more, why does the `find` return the entire dictionary and not, say, a smallest dictionary that fulfills the search? Is it searching for `{},(),[]` pairs of the keywords i.e why doesnt it return the entire page, since it contains the word `beta`

Comment: oh, my bad. honestly, you'd probably have to read through the documentation on this, but I'm using string= so it's finding the text with beta in it. You can use href=re.compile() and other ways to limit what's returned. But the only way I know to get a portion of the text returned is to operate on it as mentioned above. In reality, you can do this soup.find(string=re.compile("onkey") and it'll return the same, I just happend to choose beta.